# Optimal expression to evaluate condition and set both flag and value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Below are two functions that iterate through a collection of objects to evaluate if any items object's id is equal to the function's id argument. If true then it sets an active flag and sets the current variable to equal the id.

NOTES:

1. function longerVersion(id) if the verbose / longer approach
2. function shorterVersion(id) is my current optimal approach

QUESTION

1. Is there a better approach in ES6 and or lodash to achieve the same result?

```js
const items = {1:{id:1,active:false},2:{id:2,active:false}, 3:{id:3,active:false}}
let current = 0;

function longerVersion(id) {
  for (const k in this.items) {
    if (this.items[k].id === id) {
      this.items[k].active = true
      current = id
    } else {
      this.items[k].active = false
    }
  }
}

function shorterVersion(id) {
  for (const k in this.items) {
    items[k].active = items[k].id === id && ((current = id) && true)
  }
}

longerVersion(2);
console.log(current); // expected outcome : (current === 2)
console.log(items); // expected outcome :  items: {1:{id:1,active:false},2:{id:2,active:true}, 3:{id:3,active:false}}

shorterVersion(3);
console.log(current); // expected outcome : (current === 3)
console.log(items); // expected outcome :  items: {1:{id:1,active:false},2:{id:2,active:false}, 3:{id:3,active:true}}
```

Comment: How do you feel about switching items to be an array?  Then you could use Array.find and other useful functions instead of for loops.

Comment: "better" how? "optimal" in what sense? Personally, I hate when assignments are mixed in with Boolean expressions, but that's, like, my opinion, man.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree but then you end up with the verbose option which is code heavy

Comment: @James I'm fine with array btw, if you have a solution

Comment: And that's why we have minifiers, so we don't have to worry about crap like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `current` inside the scope of the function is a side-effect you want to avoid. Instead let it be the returning value of the function.

```js
const items = {1:{id:1,active:false},2:{id:2,active:false}, 3:{id:3,active:false}};

const functionalVersion = (items, id) => Object.values(items).reduce((acc, x) => {
  x.active = x.id === id;
  return x.active ? id : acc;
}, -1);

let current = functionalVersion(items, 2);
console.log(current); // expected outcome : (current === 2)
console.log(items); // expected outcome :  items: {1:{id:1,active:false},2:{id:2,active:true}, 3:{id:3,active:false}}

current = functionalVersion(items, 3);
console.log(current); // expected outcome : (current === 3)
console.log(items); // expected outcome :  items: {1:{id:1,active:false},2:{id:2,active:false}, 3:{id:3,active:true}}
```

The function returns a `-1` when none of the `items` id's match the id.

I don't like assignments in expressions but if that's your thing you can do it in an one-liner:

```
const functionalVersion = (items, id) => Object.values(items).reduce((acc, x) => x.active = x.id === id ? id : acc, -1);
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Brilliant! Allows me extract it to a utility function I can inject into any component. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the collection is truly a plain object and you don't need properties that are in the object's prototype chain, the `in` keyword is increasingly frowned on in favor of the newer `Object.keys` et al. Here's an approach using that, an arrow function and optional chaining, to be extra Ecma-ish:

```
function ecmaVersion(id) {
    const key = Object.keys(items).find((key) =>
        items[key].active = (items[key].id === id))
    return current = items[key]?.id
}
```

The lodash equivalent would involve [`_.findKey`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#findKey).

Comment: "the in keyword is increasingly frowned on in favor of the newer Object.keys et al" [citation needed].

Comment: Citations include [this 2012 explanation of the pitfalls](https://2ality.com/2012/01/objects-as-maps.html) and the [ESLint rule for guarding `for...in` to avoid one of them](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in). `Object.keys` and its kin just have that baked in.